# How can I move my cursor to the bottom line displayed in the current window?

Tags: vim

I've been flipping thru the help files and can't seem to find any command that would let me easily move my cursor position to the last line displayed on screen. The closest thing I can think of is the zX commands (zb, zt) but those move the window, not the cursor position.

Any ideas?

Comment: I add this link to every question asking for one of these keys because it is so useful: http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif

Comment: Yet another vim cheat sheet about [motions](http://zeitgeist.li/asset/201010/zg.nsi4.png)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to go to the bottom of window.

Actually, there are a group of commands:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>  ==> goto Head of window
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>  ==> goto Middle of window
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  ==> goto Last of window